# Searching and counting for specific words inside Excel, but excluding hidden cells/columns

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

The image above is what I want to report on; the problem is there are dozens of rows hidden, and the user David has 30 rows that are hidden that I **DON'T** want to be counted.

Now here is my issue; I need to have this referenced in two ways:

1. I need to count how many times a person's name shows up after it has been filtered for the first time.
2. I need to count (which is seen in the status field) one status as well as the person's name. Again, only the visible and not hidden.  I have tried SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIF, and all come out counting the hidden columns. I can't figure out why. As shown in the image below.

[image]

I have spent the last few hours attempting to figure out why... but I am running into a mental block, I am sure it's easy, but I can't figure it out.

If anyone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

I cannot use VBA in this instance.

The formula in one case is:

```
=COUNTIFS(Database!D:D, A4, Database!H:H,"Work in progress",Database!V:V, 1)
```

V:V is where there is a 1 or 0 for visible or not...

```
=SUBTOTAL(103, A33)
```

Comment: @Ike Could you get it working for dual searches as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "dual searches"?

Comment: @Ike User name and a status descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a helper column which displays whether a row is hidden or not and include that in your countifs function.

[image]

[image]

The formula for the flagging the row hidden/visible row status:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103;OFFSET(A3;ROW(A3:A28)-ROW(A3);0))
```

The counting formulas:

```
B33 =COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$28;$A33;$B$3:$B$28;B$32;$D$3#;1)
C33 =COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$28;$A33;$B$3:$B$28;C$32;$D$3#;1)
D33 =COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$28;A33;$D$3#;1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it when I get home, I tried the helper, so hopefully this will all work correctly :)  Thanks again.